# Java RegEx to fix HTML from Flex

Tags: java, regex, apache-flex

Need help trying to write either some RegEx or a function to fix some Adobe Flex HTML tags. We have most of them fixed, but are running into trouble with justification tags. The problem is Flex saves html from its RichTextEditor as follows:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
<P ALIGN="LEFT">
<FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size: 10pt" size="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
Test Line 1
</FONT>
</P>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
<P ALIGN="CENTER">
<FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size: 10pt" size="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
Test Line 2
</FONT>
</P>
```

We are trying to come up with a way to replace the P ALIGN="*_*_" with it's equivalent html4 tag, such as left, right, center, justify. But we also need to replace its closing tag.

The above example would become something like

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
<left>
<FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size: 10pt" size="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
Test Line 1
</FONT>
</left>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
<center>
<FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size: 10pt" size="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
Test Line 1
</FONT>
</center>
```

Anybody done anything like this?

Comment: Whenever I read a question title with both `HTML` and `Regex` in it I cringe.

Comment: It's probably better to use an HTML parser for this and not regex.

Comment: @Keppil We are in the process of running quickly away from Flex, but in the mean time have to keep our old application working...unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am just thinking of using tow regex with some manual manipulation as below:

```
      String startingTagPattern = "<P ALIGN=\"[\\w]\">";
      String endTagPattern = "</p>";
```

Now if startingTagPattern is matched, get the matching tag line as :

```
      String tagLine = match.group(0);
      String alignString = tagLine.substring(8,tagLine.lastIndexOf("\""));
```

Now you may put the tags in output as:

```
      String startTag = "<"+alignString+">";
      String endTag = "</"+alignString+">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use regex to replace the p align tags with their respective values.

For an input like

```
<P ALIGN="LEFT">xyz</P><SomeTag></SomeTag><P ALIGN="CENTER">xyz</P>;
```

Here's the code,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String str = "<P ALIGN=\"LEFT\">xyz</P><SomeTag></SomeTag><P ALIGN=\"CENTER\">xyz</P>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)<(P ALIGN=\")([^\"]+)([^>]+)>([^<]+)<([^>]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while(matcher.find()) {         
            str = str.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1), ""); // replaces <p align
            str = str.replaceFirst(matcher.group(3), ""); // replaces the single quote after LEFT or CENTER
            str = str.replaceFirst(matcher.group(5), "/" + matcher.group(2)); // replaces /P from the ending tag with /LEFT or /CENTER 
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Output

```
<LEFT>xyz</LEFT><SomeTag></SomeTag><CENTER>xyz</CENTER>
```